What must nginx setup be to host an application in a sub folder
I am on a VPS running Ubuntu 22.04.4 I have a folder called founders located at /home/founders/founders. That folder belongs to a user founder which is in a group called founders.
I have a Django app and I serve it using gunicorn and it is managed by the supervisor app. The Django app is located at /home/founders/founders/back
I have a domain called founderslooking.com and it is pointing to the server IP of the VPS the files are on.
The Django app is running fine on the domain and I am able to register and log in. The Django app also has an API located at founderslooking.com/api/v1 and I can access it fine along with any endpoint.
If I am logged in then there is a button that will take me to a Vue application that I want to run at founderslooking.com/app but it's not working. The production Vue app is located at /home/founders/founders/dist and that folder also belongs to user founder.
Here is the Django app's Nginx configuration (founders.conf) and like I said it runs perfectly:
upstream founders_app_server {
        server unix:/home/founders/founders/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name founderslooking.com;

        client_max_body_size 4G;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

                proxy_redirect off;

                if (!-f $request_filename) {
                        proxy_pass http://founders_app_server;
                }

                # auth_basic "Testing";
                # auth_basic_user_file /home/founders/founders/.htpasswd;
        }
        location /static/ {
                autoindex on;
                root /home/founders/founders/back;
        }
}

Here is my Vue app's Nginx configuration (app.conf) that isn't working because going to founderslooking.com/app/user/1 which is the logged in user gives me a Not Found page. The same goes for founderslooking.com/app.
server {
    listen 80;

    root /home/founders/founders/dist;
    index index.html;

    location /app/ {
        alias /home/site/dist/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}

My understanding of how Nginx works is if I go to founderslooking.com/app then I should see my Vue app because of this part:
    location /app/ {
        alias /home/site/dist/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

But instead I get Not Found. If I add a server_name founderslooking.com; to my app.conf then I can see my Vue app but I cannot see my Django site and nothing on the Vue side works.
Help is really appreciated thanks.

Probably you need your app to know it'll be mounted to a "subfolder" rather than to a root. Sometimes there is an autodetection, sometimes isn't. In Django, you need to set it up at least in your root urls.py properly.

Where are your files stored? /home/site/dist/ or /home/site/dist/app/?

Django is an application, not just static files you serve. You will need Django running as an application and then you can use Nginx to proxy_pass requests to it.

Django app is working fine. The Vue app is a separate app that uses the Django app as a backend. The Vue files are located in /home/site/dist. I presume /app is just telling Nginx if someone goes to domain.com/app serve the files in /home/site/dist or is that not how it works?

The edit was the same as the question, diffing them I see only an added empty nonbreaking space. To serve both your Django app and Vue app on the same domain using Nginx, you need to ensure the configuration directs traffic appropriately for each application. The key is to correctly set up the location blocks and avoid conflicts between the configurations.
This should work for both your Django app and Vue app:
upstream founders_app_server {
    server unix:/home/founders/founders/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name founderslooking.com;

    client_max_body_size 4G;

    # Django app configuration
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://founders_app_server;
        }
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/founders/founders/back/static/;
        autoindex on;
    }

    # Vue app configuration
    location /app/ {
        alias /home/founders/founders/dist/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /app/index.html;
    }

    # Ensure that other static files for the Vue app are served correctly
    location /app/static/ {
        alias /home/founders/founders/dist/static/;
    }
}

I feel that I'm derailing from the original question, but your new explanation seems more straight forward.
upstream founders_app_server defines the Gunicorn socket for the Django app.
listen 80; listens on port 80 for HTTP traffic.
server_name founderslooking.com; specifies the domain name.
Django App:
The main location / is set up to proxy requests to the Gunicorn server if the requested file does not exist.
location /static/ is set up to serve static files from the Django app's static directory.
Vue App Configuration:
location /app/ is set up to serve the Vue app. It uses alias to point to the Vue app's dist directory and try_files to handle the HTML5 history mode by redirecting requests to /app/index.html.
location /app/static/ is added to ensure that any static files within the Vue app's static directory are served correctly.
Save the combined configuration to a file, like this: /etc/nginx/sites-available/founders.conf.
Create a symlink to the configuration file in the sites-enabled directory:
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/founders.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

Test the Nginx configuration for syntax errors and reload Nginx to apply the changes:
sudo nginx -t
sudo systemctl reload nginx

That should do it to access your Django application at founderslooking.com and your Vue application at founderslooking.com/app.

Thank you at least now the Vue application works but it is not running inside domain/app it is running on the main domain which is not what I want as I have two separate apps. How do I make the vue app run inside domain.com/app?

If I just go to domain.com/app then I see the nginx welcome page. But I want to go to domain.com/app/user/1 which is the route of the logged in user, so how do I set up nginx to be able to run the Vue app inside domain.com/app/*

Also on the main site why can I not access the api which is located at domain.com/api/v1/?

The issue is that the location /app/ block is correctly serving the Vue app, but it's also handling requests that should go to the /api/v1/ endpoint. To fix this, you need to add a specific location block for the API endpoint so that it doesn't get overridden by the Vue app's location block. I changed the code above, I hope it helps.

Thanks Max but it's not working. I changed my question completely and added as much information as possible about the entire set up.

I changed the code, I hope it helps!

Thank you so much at least now I see blank pages and not the Not Found but the Vue site is not loading because of an error in the console for both css and js files. The error is '*.js was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”)'. The static files for the Vue app are located at /home/founders/founders/dist/assets and tried to add it to the nginx conf file but it didn't work and I get the same error in the console. Also tried app/static like in your answer but that didn't work either.

It's a Vue issue and after reading up on it I managed to get it working I just now have to fix a few stuff on the Vue side. Thanks a lot for all your help Max

You are welcome! If I've been helpful to solved the issue, a +1 would be nice :-)

I tried doing +1 but they say my reputation is too low. I'm still new sorry
